# Docker. Phpmyadmin does not see the port assigned to it

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin

I am using the following docker configuration:

```
version: "3"

services:
  database:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1009
    restart: "always"
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: database
    restart: "always"
    depends_on:
      - database
```

It works, but if I change the mysql port for my PC to `- "3360:3306"` (for example 3306 may be busy with the main mysql service running on the computer) - it stops working. If I do this, I will be able to connect to mysql from my computer in CMD like `mysql -u root -P 3360 -p`, but phpmyadmin will give the error - connection refused.

No matter what I do, I see this error. For example I used the following docker configuration:

```
version: "3"

services:
  database:
    image: mysql
    networks:
      - my-network
    ports:
      - "3360:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1009
    restart: "always"
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    links:
      - database
    networks:
      - my-network
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: database
      PMA_PORT: 3360
    restart: "always"
    depends_on:
      - database

networks:
  my-network:
```

Even all of this didn't work. Phpmyadmin gave out one inscription when trying to connect - Connection refused all the time. But it still worked in the terminal.

Why can't I use a different port for phpmyadmin in docker?

Comment: PHPMyAdmin needs to use `3306`, no matter what port is bound to the outside. It doesn't connect through the outside.

Comment: @tkausl, ok, but then why do we need a constant PMA_PORT ?